# Cycle through / add name of clipping feature to output of clips in Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a feature class named Study Areas with multiple polygons, named in an attribute field as Study Area A, B, C, etc.

I will be using these polygons to clip various polygon feature classes that represent different landscape attributes, like Land Cover, Soils, etc.  The end goal is an analysis of how much of each type of Land Cover acreage is within Study Area A, B, and so on.

I would like to do this through Model Builder (I don't know Python) but need to find a way that I could create outputs that have the Study Area name appended onto them so that the outputs can be easily organized (there's going to be hundreds of outputs).

So running through the model, I would need 1) a component that cycles through the Study Area feature class so that only one study area polygon is used for clipping at a time and 2) a clipped output named something like Study_Area_A_Land_Cover

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of ArcGIS you are using you may use the [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) method which would precede your clip tool to pull the attribute value into a variable (Insert menu>Create Variable option), which may be consumed through an [in-line variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000060000000) into your output layer name.

Check out this link below for some case examples:

[Examples of using iterators in ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/)

Answer (score 1):

Artwork is right, but note that the [split_analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000) tool does what you want. You just need to make sure that you have a field column with valid output names.

Comment: Split analysis is actually an extra step that is not necessary for the required workflow.  Once the feature is selected only this feature will be used as the target clip feature.